# How to fix "value is invalid" error cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have a dotnet mvc application running with sql server database. in just one of the input forms, i cannot submit the input, browser gives an error, "value is invalid"

in the model:

```
[Range(0,Int16.MaxValue)]
public Int16? price{ get; set; }
```

in the view of the model:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Price</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

all other forms are working well, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well... What kind of value are you inputting in that field?

Comment: what is the input value being provided

Comment: It is integer. @VDWWD

Comment: any integer that is not greater than int16. @EhsanSajjad

Comment: You have a nullable int which may be the problem. Have you tried something like `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.price ?? 0,` etc.

Comment: Just tested your code and works fine. Are you certain a decimal isn't being added? ie 10.20 as the field is "Price" after all

Comment: @SWilko, I can also confirm it works as it should.

Comment: @Steve, i have tried your suggestion but it gives an error before compilation, i get "Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'" error. I tried to make the price column not nullable from the database, but it did not solved the problem..

Comment: @SWilko I am sure i am giving an integer as input, could it be because of the browser?

Comment: @FatihKıyıkçı dont think so..only thing I can think of is to clear your browser cache as may have "old" code stored there.

Comment: Can you show us the actual HTML that is generated for `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })` when you open the page in your browser?

Comment: I suppose this is the html generated. @Kei `<input class="input-validation-error form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="price field must be a number." data-val-required="price field is required." id="price" name="price" type="number" value="6">`

Comment: I think "Int16.MaxValue" may be the problem.  Just use "32767" and use standard Int as type.  (but price seems like it should be a decimal, no?)

Comment: @pcalkins I have tried it with many datatypes, even when it is int, decimal, etc... Still gives the error.

Comment: Check to be sure changes are migrated after updating the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trying everything i can, i have found the problem.
In my model, the name of the field is "price". In my controller;

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "price_id,price")] Price price, int id)
```

the problem was i was giving the name "price" in the controller, to the instance of the Price table in the parameters. I changed it to something else, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nullable `Int16` which can be problem, you maybe providing space or null to the price property.

put null check if value is null then there should a zero value by default.
Something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.price ?? 0)
```

Comment: I have found the issue, and posted it as an answer. Still thanks for answering.